# Online Poker with Microphones and Video Cameras

Tags: poker-tools

Has anyone played a game of poker online where all the players were required to have microphones and headphones?  If so, how did you change your game based on what you heard or saw?

Comment: what client does support that? or are you talking about a session with friends? where you all sit on a private table in some online casino and use mic in teamspeak as well?

Comment: Not too many have it at the moment.  I'm a software developer who is working on creating a client that supports it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any client that supports that option, but it would give me an advantage. One of the key elements in poker is to observe your opponents.

If I would play in a game with headset and cam, I assume, I only would play on that one table. So I have more time to concentrate on the observation. Try to find out how my opponents react.

Are they getting chatty when they don't have good hands? Are they getting quiet when they do? If with camera: what ARE their faces telling me in certain situations?

Take notes or use a tool like Pokertracker. They have won with a made hand. What did his body language tell me? Did e folded a 3-bet? What did his body language tell me?

[This](http://www.pokerology.com/lessons/studying-your-opponents/) is a pretty interesting gathering of thoughts on observation:

> **The Best Way to Study Players**
>
> Increasing levels of familiarity will help you with this task. That’s
>   another way of saying that as you continue to watch your opponents,
>   you’ll pick up things later on that you probably won’t see initially.
>   So it’s best to look at the big-picture things first.
>
> What’s obvious and available for all to see? When first sitting down
>   at the table, look for skill signs and begin correlating your
>   opponents’ play with the hands they turn up at showdown. You can
>   easily do both at the same time.
>
> Poker skill signs are easily found in live poker games. How
>   comfortable is your opponent with the game, the speed of play, and the
>   others at the table? Is he comfortable with his chips? Does he riffle
>   them with an air of sureness and certainty that suggests he spends
>   hours upon hours at the card table? Sure, there are poker players
>   graced with manual dexterity who can riffle chips like a
>   slight-of-hand artist and can’t play worth a damn – but there’s
>   usually some correlation between these things and skill.
>
> In some cases it may be very high. In others, not at all. But you have
>   to start somewhere and if your opponent is at ease with the game’s
>   mechanics, give him credit for being able to play, but be ever
>   vigilant and willing to downgrade that rating based on information
>   gathered later.

Long story short. Playing online poker with microphones and cameras would affect my play - other than the need to put on pants - with the given opportunity to gather more informations about my opponents and study their mind.

Answer (score 0):

888 Poker offers a few tables ... 
but I didn t pay to much attention , because 
A: it is likely that they play other tables too ... so you can t really know if something you think is a tell really applys to your table .
and B: I think you will see a lot of Fake Tells . 
I didn t enjoy playing there because most players had really bad soundquality or playing music in background ... so it gets really bad when you have background noises from 5 other players .